# Laravel returned error not shown in front-end

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have something like this in a Laravel API for one of the routes:

```
return response()->json(['message' =>  "Couldn't Price the car"], 500);
```

In the front-end, I have

```
try {
 let data = await Axios.get("blax", {});    
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

`err.message` just shows default message:

> request failed with status code 500

instead of showing:

> Couldn't Price the car

How do I show my custom message?

Comment: Did you check the response content on your browser's network tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using `err.response.message`

```
try{
 let data = await Axios.get("blax", {});

}catch(err){
  console.log(err.response.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Updated

`responseJSON` is not defined it's just `response`

try this the `console.log(err.response.message)` as following:

```
try{
 let data = await Axios.get("blax", {});

}catch(err){
  console.log(err.response.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it catches perfectly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data: {
    response: null,
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      let data = await axios.get("https://httpstat.us/500", {});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ss', err.message);
      this.response = err.message;
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
Error: {{response}}
</div>
```

If you want to minimize your code, you can do `.catch` directly on the axios call, like so:

```
let data = axios.get("https://httpstat.us/500", {}).catch(e => e.message);
```

This catch also uses arrow function stripped down to the minimal. Here is an example of the same arrow function, just "normal":

```
let data = axios.get("https://httpstat.us/500", {}).catch((e) => {return e.message});
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data: {
    response: null,
  },
  async created() {
    this.response = await axios.get("https://httpstat.us/500", {}).catch(e => e.message);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
Error: {{response}}
</div>
```